# R: Select names of a data.frame using levels() function

Tags: r, subset, levels

I have two data.frames `input` and `filelist` which are subset with the code below

```
input <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Example2", "Example7", "Test", "Test2","Test3", "Test6", "Test77"), class = "factor"), REFERENCE = structure(c(2L,2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("EXAMPLE5", "REGION1", "REGION2", "REGION77"), class = "factor"), VALUE = structure(c(1L,1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("120", "13", "14", "65", "89", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "REFERENCE", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))


filelist <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("","Example2", "Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test6"), class = "factor"), REFERENCE = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("",  "EXAMPLE5", "REGION1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME","REFERENCE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(dplyr)
ana <- filelist %>% left_join(., input)

     NAME REFERENCE VALUE
1     Test   REGION1   120
2    Test3   REGION1    89
3                     <NA>
4    Test6  EXAMPLE5    14
5    Test2  EXAMPLE5    65
6 Example2  EXAMPLE5     C
```

and then written into different data.frames:

```
list2env(split(ana, f = ana$REFERENCE )[-1], .GlobalEnv)
```

This all works fine, but what I am trying to do in a next step is to access the NAMES for the group `REGION1` (the result will later be part of a legend where I dont want all the different items in, only those selected). I am trying to do this with the `levels()` command

```
NAMES_REGION1 <- levels(REGION1$NAME)
```

but my output is the following:

```
[1] ""         "Example2" "Test"     "Test2"    "Test3"    "Test6"
```

what I would like to have as output is only `"Test"` and `"Test3"` because only they are part of the group `REGION1` .
Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `REGION1` was produced from a larger data set, you'll want to drop the excess levels carried over after the subset.  You can use `droplevels`

```
REGION1$NAME <- droplevels(REGION1$NAME)
levels(REGION1$NAME)
# [1] "Test"  "Test3"
```

Notice that the `REFERENCE` column also has levels that were carried over.  You can remove the extra levels in both columns at once with

```
REGION1[-3] <- lapply(REGION1[-3], droplevels)
```

Now we can see that all extra levels are gone

```
lapply(REGION1[-3], levels)
# $NAME
# [1] "Test"  "Test3"
#
# $REFERENCE
# [1] "REGION1"
```

Comment: another question has come up. what if i wanted to use `nlevels()` in this way? `nREGION1<-nlevels(REGION1$NAME)`

Comment: `nlevels` is for getting the number of levels, so that should work after you do `droplevels`

Comment: yes, it works perfectly. One problem which is missing in my sample data: I sometimes have NAMES that have more than one row, e.g. two rows with "Test" and 3 rows with "Test3". What could I use to only filter them out ONCE, not like with levels() which lists every item. In general I would like to have the same output as above just the input data is different (I can change it if desired)

Comment: so my input data would look like this: `input <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Example2", "Example7", "Test", "Test2","Test3", "Test6", "Test77"), class = "factor"), REFERENCE = structure(c(2L,2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("EXAMPLE5", "REGION1", "REGION2", "REGION77"), class = "factor"), VALUE = structure(c(1L,1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("120", "13", "14", "65", "89", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "REFERENCE", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))`

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is.  It still works the same after I run your whole code again using the different `input` data frame.  Perhaps ask a new question that links to this one

Comment: sorry I had problems in my data with data conversion, I had integer and numeric data, solved my problem by using `as.factor()`. Thank you again!